# Magento 2 - Where can I find the parameters from my external application sent to magento via rest api?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I'm making a request to magento 2 via REST API to "/rest/V1/carts/mine" from a external application.

I have set a breakpoint at the first line in index.php of magento 2 and inspect the variables and superglobals from xdebug, but I can't find the parameters anywhere.

Where are they?

Answer (score 0):

`/rest/V1/carts/mine` resolves to different classes and methods based on the **HTTP Request Method Type**

If you are making a **GET** request set your Xdebug breakpoint to

> Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement::getCartForCustomer()

If you are making a **POST** request set your Xdebug breakpoint to

> Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement::createEmptyCartForCustomer()

If you are making a **PUT** request set your Xdebug breakpoint to

> Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository::save()